# ScrollView should stop scrolling at once it reaches the end

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Its normal that no one wants to scroll unnecessarily once the scroll has reached its end. I have implemented the following code which works perfect when the scroll is stable at the top/bottom position.

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -1
        {
            scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
            self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
            scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        }
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height))
        {

            scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
            scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        }
}
```

But if user drags rapidly to top or bottom, the scrolling immediately doesn't stop scrolling when it reaches to top/bottom, but rather takes some time to halt. **Can we do something that scroll will halt immediately when scrolling reaches the ends and not accelerate further?**

Comment: Have you tried disabling bounce?

Comment: @Iyuna No I didn't. Those are the only codes that I have implemented.

Comment: Try to set scrollView.bounces = false in your initialization method and check if it provides the behaviour that you're expecting.

Comment: @Iyuna Thanks it worked....!!

Comment: can you please explain in details i have same issue here

Comment: @user1374Try turning off scroll views bouncing